# Stripping paint from old fireplace last step - any advice to achieve clean finish?

Tags: fireplace, paint-removal

As you can tell from the photos below, there is still yet some paint residue, like a foggy layer on top of the brick. We're not sure what the best way to get this off  or if this is about as good as we can get it. Looking for adivce like maybe some other chemical or a way to polish the extra mile. Any advice or recommendations?

PS: We used "Multi-Strip" from Home Depot to remove the other layers. Have used steel brush, scraper, and water and sponges.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Subject to various caveats, either a heat gun (electric) or a torch (fuel/air) might help.

...If you have not already tested if the paint on there was lead-based, do that, and if it was, don't do this.

...Ventilate really, really well. Even without lead, likely to be a bunch of stuff you don't want to breathe coming off. A charcoal filter (organic fumes) respirator might be a very good idea as well.

...Don't burn the house down. The brick won't burn but working along the edges can be risky.

Painting brick is one of those things that is easy to do, and VERY hard to undo.

While I doubt it, being paint, you could experiment with an acid on a small patch - probably vinegar (acetic, 5 or 10%) as being relatively low hazard and probably already in your house. Muriatic (hydrochloric) is more common in masonry uses and stronger, but also more hazardous. In either case follow label instructions and neutralize with a baking soda and water solution or other base when done. But that's more for cleaning any "mortar haze" off the face of bricks from the mortar in the joints, and I doubt it would help much with paint residue.

Comment: A (RIP) home improvement editor in the Boston Globe used to say "there's a special place in hell for those that paint brick"

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely that you can get any better than that, because the paint will have soaked into the pores of the brick and it might be too deep to get rid of it by grinding the surface down. You might try staining it.